# Number of one-to-one functions between $\{0, 1\}$ and $\{1, 2, 3, ..., 9\}$

Tags: combinatorics, functions

First off, these are kind of confusing me. I'm not entirely sure what the question is asking. Would someone be willing to explain what the question is asking?

> Count the total number of different one-to-one functions from the set $\{0, 1\}$ into the set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 9\}$

My guess is that we are assigning numbers from the second set in place in the first set, so the first number in the first set could be $1$ to $9$ and same for the second, giving you $9 \cdot 9 = 9^2 = 81$. However, the term one-to-one leads me to believe that I'm counting more solutions than I should. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can correct your answer by subtracting the $9$ constant functions from the $81$ functions you found.  If the domain has more than two elements, the approach taken in the answers by Parcly Taxel and Cameron Eggins is preferable.

Comment: Check the source of your problem statement.  "One-to-one function" is used by the vast majority of authors to mean a function that is both $1-1$ (injective) and *onto* (surjective).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, so one-to-one or injective functions mean that if $f(a) = f(b)$ then $a=b$, i.e. two elements in the domain cannot map to the same element in the codomain. Thus, there are only $9*8=72$ possible functions. I.e. choose 9 possible values for 0 to map to, then choose from the other 8 values for 1 to map to.

Comment: Just to further clarify and solidify:  So, I assume in one instance, you'd have (1,X), where x is 2-9, then (2,X), where X is 1 or 3-9, basically meaning that you can put 9 numbers in the first position in the set, but only 8 in the second.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah exactly. And then you can extend this for a domain of $n$ elements into a set of $k$ elements where $k \geq n$, which would give $\frac{k!}{(k-n)!}$ different injective functions.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is

- 9 choices for the image of 0
- 8 choices for the image of 1 (the image of 0 is taken)

leading to 72 one-to-one functions.